# dynamic content alignment issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gkMLw/1/

```
   .highcharts-legend-item:nth-of-type(1)
 {
   font-weight:bold;
 }
```

I want the second and third spans also to be aligned the same as 1.

The content is dynamic so I cant add any new id or class to the markup.

With the existing markup is there any way I can make it to align via css?

Comment: Please try to refrain from using `position:absolute` for **everything**. This is precisely why it's not a good idea.

Comment: First of all, please avoid using inline styles. It makes your code unreadable and hard to work with - [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS). Once you do so, hopefully you'll find the answer by yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by "aligned"? It's not clear at all.

Comment: @TJ I have something like this to return '<div><span style="float:left;width:125px">' + name + '</span><span>' + score + '</span><span style="margin-left:38%">' + rank + '</span></div>';

Comment: @ralph.m the 1,2,3 should be on one line

Comment: This markup is dynamically created and i am using highcharts plugin where all thes classes are defaultly built in which I need to customise

Comment: check this...i found the solution..thnaks guys for looking..http://jsfiddle.net/gkMLw/8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rkmq8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mind

I got the answer

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gkMLw/8/

```
.highcharts-legend-item:nth-of-type(1) div span:nth-of-type(3)
{
    margin-left:31% !important;
}
```

Comment: The way you did makes no sense to us. Anyway, it makes sense to you. Happy coding :)

Comment: That's a bad solution.. if any number in your html changes, your alignment won't hold..

Comment: in my solution i always have 2 numbers  and 2 decimals..so there wont be any issue i guess

Answer (score 2):

This is basically tabular data do you should be using a table. However you can simplify your mark-up and use CSS tables as follows:

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkMLw/7/)

**Revised HTML**

```
<div class="highcharts-legend-item">
    <div class="test">
        <span>Stefen Lee Liberti</span>
        <span>26.10</span>
        <span>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        <span>Angelique Lyle</span> 
        <span>19.77</span>
        <span>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        <span>Endre Barath, Jr.</span>
        <span>18.22</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.highcharts-legend-item {
    display: table;
    width:80%; /* or whatever */
}

.test {
    display: table-row;
}

.test span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: left; /* or whatever */
    border:1px solid red; /* for visual reference */
}
```

However, if you cannot change the HTML structure you can still use teh same properties but youhave to be more selective

[**Existing Mark-up JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkMLw/11/)

Answer (score 0):

i have corrected your [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rkmq8/)

```
.highcharts-legend-item {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Changes in css and sytle class

Answer (score 0):

I just add the styles what you are expecting. Don't use the inline styline. Use proper class names.

for the third div you have used class "`highcharts -legend-item`" instead of

`highcharts-legend-item`

[Demo URL](http://jsfiddle.net/gkMLw/10/)